# Requests in Vuejs returning different response than Postman from django rest-framework backend

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, request

I have been trying to implement the [Twitch user authorization code flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth#oauth-authorization-code-flow). I am working on getting the authorization url generated from the django backend and pass it to my Vue front end so the user can open the user authorization page.

Postman recovers the generated url perfectly however when i try to do the same in Vue using Requests it is giving me an entirely different object.

```
Object { _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, uri: {…}, method: "POST", readable: true, writable: true, explicitMethod: true, _qs: {…}, _auth: {…}, … }
auth.js:37:12
```

and here is what Postman returns

```
"{\"url\": \"https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize\", \"client_id\": \"xafkse7a6uyor8uisaet1ma36mrp9l\", \"response_type\": \"code\", \"grant_type\": \"token\", \"scope\": \"user_read\"}"
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this. Below is the code used to get to this point.

views.py

```
import json
import os
import requests
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status

# get user access token
@api_view(['POST'])
def get_twitch_user_token_uri(request):
    endpoint = "https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize"

    token_url = {
        'url': endpoint,
        'client_id': settings['TWITCH_CLIENT_ID'],
        'response_type': 'code',
        'grant_type': 'token',
        'scope': 'user_read'
    }
    return JsonResponse(token_url , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Login.vue

```
methods: {
    login() {
      const authenticating = true;
      this.$store.dispatch("auth/get_twitch_user_token_uri", authenticating);
    }
  }
```

auth.js

```
const actions = {
  get_twitch_user_token_uri({ commit, state }) {
    commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI);
    console.log(this.endpoint);
    return auth.twitch_token(this.endpoint)
      .then(({ data }) => commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN, data))
      .then(() => commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_SUCCESS))
      .catch(() => commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_FAILURE));
  },
}

const mutations = {
  [GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI](state) {
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login";
    state.authenticating = true;
    const r = request.post(url);
    this.endpoint = r;
  },
}
```

Above is where the error starts to occur requesting the url from my django backend. I'm sure i'm overlooking something i just don't know why it would return a the wrong response.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to do with the way i was calling the request and passing data from actions to mutations.

Login.vue

```
methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store.dispatch("auth/get_twitch_user_token_uri");
      // .then(() => this.$router.push("/"));
    }
  }
```

auth.js

```
const actions = {
  async get_twitch_user_token_uri({ commit }) {
    commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI);
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    };
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login", options);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      commit(SET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI, data);
      return commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI_SUCCESS);
    } catch (e) {
      return commit(GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI_FAILURE);
    }
  },
}

const mutations = {
  [GET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI](state) {
    state.authenticating = true;
  },
  [SET_TWITCH_TOKEN_URI](state, data) {
    state.endpoint = data;
  },
}
```